# hide and show without resizing the table element

Tags: jquery

[image: comment without flag]
[image]

if you notice, above are comments in stackoverflow, the above image shows no flag while below image shows the flag shows when the mouse is hovering the comment. The flag is hide/show without resizing the table layout. But I have tried my own way by using below code but it still resizing.

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function()
{
    $('#hover').hover(function()
    {
        $('#flag').show();
    });
});
```

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="hover">

            <div id="flag" style="display:none">
                <img src="flag.png"/>
            </div>
            
            <div>
                Hover me
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Help me out here how to resolve this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS, you need to set an explicit width of the `#flag` element, then toggle the display of the `img` itself.

```
​#flag {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    float: left;
}

#flag > img {
    display: none;
}
```

Then your jQuery code gets adapted:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#hover').mouseenter(function()
    {
        $('#flag > img').show();
    }).mouseleave(function()
    {
        $('#flag > img').hide();
    });
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WpvGN/) for it in action.

Comment: i'm also improving my code with using mouseenter and mouseleave. very helpful

Answer (score 1):

`hover` takes 2 handlers for `mouseenter` and `mouseout`. When you pass only one handler, the same handler is executed for both the events. So in your case the flag will always be visible. You should pass another handler to hide the flag on `mouseout`. Another problem is  you are using `document` as a string. Remove the quotes from your code.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#hover').hover(function()
    {
        $('#flag').show();
    },
    function()
    {
        $('#flag').hide();
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3tsy2/)**

Answer (score 1):

try to change your HTML like following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="hover">

            <div id="flag" style="display:none;float:left;">
                <img src="flag.png"/>
            </div>

            <div style="margin-left:18px">
                Hover me
            </div>
          </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/9agPb/1/
​

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the code, but with the approach. Instead of having the `div` with a `display:none` you should have an empty `div` and then populate the content during the hover event. This is the approach that stackoverflow does, albeit with `td` instead of `div`.

Alternatively, you can change `display:none` to `visibility:hidden`, as the latter does not remove  the item from the document flow, and therefore there will be no resizing when it is made visible.

Comment: i'm using visibility:hidden in input form.